# Get Active Directory Administrators using Azure AD Graph Client

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, user-roles

Using the Azure Active Directory Graph Client, I can successfully query the AD for its user roles with the ff. code:

```
var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(); // Instantiate the Graph Client here.
var adRoles = await activeDirectoryClient.DirectoryRoles.ExecuteAsync();
```

Is it possible, however, to get:

1. **A list of roles that are admin roles**?, and
2. **A list of users who fall under the admin roles**?

In this case, my definition of an admin would be users under the *Company Administrator* role, or those who would be able to authorize an application (via the auth request URL with format https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx-xxx&resource=yyy-yyy&redirect_uri=zzz-zzz&**prompt=admin_consent**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this and let's look at the REST API as a starting point.

You can get a list of groups and roles per **USER** using making a GET request to: [https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/$links/memberOf?api-version](https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/%7Buser_id%7D/$links/memberOf?api-version)

On success, returns a collection of links to the Group's and DirectoryRole's that this user is a member of

ref: [Get a user's group and directory role memberships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#OperationsonusernavigationpropertiesGetausersgroupanddirectoryrolememberships)

To get the membership of a group you would make a GET request to: [https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/{object_id}/$links/members?api-version](https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/%7Bobject_id%7D/$links/members?api-version)

ref: [Get a group's direct members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/groups-operations#GetGroupMembers)

However per the docs:

> No functions or actions may be called on directory roles

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#DirectoryRoleEntity

This has to be done from the USER object. The SDK will reflect this.

```
IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> pagedCollection = retrievedUserFetcher.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync();
```

The GraphAPI console app has some great examples that should show you how to complete these actions: [Program.cs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/Program.cs)

Comment: Thanks for the input @Devian. I created a test method and was able to verify that my company admin had a `Role` object which, when cross-referenced with the roles of the active directory, matched up with the AD's "Company Administrators" role.


That being said, is it a guarantee that every AD will have this role, with the name "Company Administrator"? I assume the role ID will change with each tenant, but if the name is a constant, I do not mind using it for comparison. It is likely that I will have to loop through all members to check if they match the role to get all of the AD admins.